# How to color a button on button click?

Tags: javascript, html

**I an trying to color button on another button click..but its not working for.**

```
function show_col(){
    console.log("hello");
       var path=localStorage.getItem(".physics_section  #color1 button");
      $(''+path+'').css("background","green");
      $(''+path+'').css("color","white");
}
```

when show_col() function get called and it  print "hello" to console but last three didn't get executed.when i put these three line directly to console it work fine but working with simple function call.

```
function color_ans(e){

    $('.physics_section #color1 button').removeClass('selected');
    $('.physics_section  #color1 #'+e+'').addClass('selected');
    localStorage.setItem('.physics_section  #color1 button','.physics_section  #color1 #'+e+'')
}
```

**Button that call function:**

```
 <button id='cit"+i+"' onclick='doThing_chemistry(event);show_col();'>"+i+"</button>
```

Comment: can you please mention that whether these both bottons are in a same page or in different pages?

Comment: both button are on same page same page ..but the problem is  when show_col function get called after executing console.log rest css part doesnot get executed..

Answer (score 0):

what's  the value of   e  when you call color_ans(e)

try  ID  '#cit'+e

```
localStorage.setItem('.physics_section  #color1 button','.physics_section  #color1 #cit'+e)
```